# How to open another app from my app if it is installed or open playstore if it is not installed?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open another application from my application like this inside onclick listner

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Mainactivity.this, com.pkg.classname)
   startActivity(intent);
```

It does not work.

I want to open the app if installed or open in playstore if not installed.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
Context ctx=this;
try {
    Intent i = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app");
    ctx.startActivity(i);
} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.example.app")));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app")));
    }
}
```